# How to apply a DASL filter in AdvancedSearch?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I adapted code so I can reply to the latest email.

I loop through a range of cells in my spreadsheet to get a string to find the email in my inbox or sent items.

The code sometimes finds and opens the email thread and sometimes it won't.

Is the syntax of my filter correct?

```vb
searchString = "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription ci_phrasematch" & supNumber
```

I commented these lines otherwise it won't stop looping:

```vb
While searchComplete = False
'        DoEvents
Wend
```

The event handler `OutlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete` never fires

The following code is saved in a class module:

```vb
Option Explicit

' Credits: Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909315/advanced-search-complete-event-not-firing-in-vba

' Event handler for outlook
Dim WithEvents OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outlookSearch As Outlook.Search
Dim outlookResults As Outlook.Results

Dim searchComplete As Boolean
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "Kernel32" () As Long


Sub Minuterie(Milliseconde As Long)
    Dim Arret As Long
    Arret = GetTickCount() + Milliseconde
    Do While GetTickCount() < Arret
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub


' Handler for Advanced search complete
Private Sub OutlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
    MsgBox "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired."
    searchComplete = True
End Sub


Sub SearchAndReply(program_number As Range, searchFolderName As String, searchSubFolders As Boolean)

    ' Declare objects variables
    Dim customMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim resultItem As Integer
    Dim supNumber As String
    Dim compName As String
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim strTag As String
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    ' Variable defined at the class level
    'Dim outlookSearch As Outlook.Search
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    
    strTag = "BodySearch"
    
    ' Variable defined at the class level (modified by outlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete when search is completed)
    searchComplete = False
     
    supNumber = "'" & program_number.Value & "'"
    searchString = "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription ci_phrasematch" & supNumber
    
    ' Perform advanced search
    Set outlookSearch = OutlookApp.AdvancedSearch(searchFolderName, searchString, searchSubFolders)
        Minuterie 2000
    ' Wait until search is complete based on outlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete event
'    While searchComplete = False
'        DoEvents
'    Wend

    ' Get the results
    Set outlookResults = outlookSearch.Results

    If outlookResults.Count = 0 Then
        program_number.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Sort descending so you get the latest
    outlookResults.Sort "[SentOn]", True

    ' Reply only to the latest one
    resultItem = 1

    ' Some properties you can check from the email item for debugging purposes
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print outlookResults.Item(resultItem).SentOn, outlookResults.Item(resultItem).ReceivedTime, outlookResults.Item(resultItem).SenderName, outlookResults.Item(resultItem).subject
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set customMailItem = outlookResults.Item(resultItem).ReplyAll

    ' At least one reply setting is required in order to replyall to fire
    'customMailItem.Body = "Just a reply text " & customMailItem.Body
    customMailItem.HTMLBody = "<p> Thank you <p>" & customMailItem.HTMLBody

    customMailItem.Display
    program_number.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                         
End Sub
```

I saved the following code in regular module in Excel:

```vb
Public Sub ProcessEmails()

    Dim testOutlook As Object
    Dim oOutlook As clsOutlook
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim subjectCell As Range
    Dim OGDD_Programs As Range
    Dim searchFolderName As String
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim Sup_ENg_Number As Range

    ' Start outlook if it isn't opened (credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328314/how-to-open-outlook-with-vba)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set testOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If testOutlook Is Nothing Then
        Shell ("OUTLOOK")
    End If

    ' Initialize Outlook class
    Set oOutlook = New clsOutlook

    ' Get the outlook inbox and sent items folders path (check the scope specification here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch)
    searchFolderName = "'" & Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).FolderPath & "','" & Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).FolderPath & "'"
'
'    ' Loop through excel cells with subjects
'    Set searchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")
    'set a reference to cells we are going to loop through
    Set OGDD_Programs = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each Sup_ENg_Number In OGDD_Programs
      If (Sup_ENg_Number.Interior.Color = vbYellow Or Sup_ENg_Number.Interior.Color = vbRed) Then
      
        Else

            ' Only to cells with actual subjects
            If Sup_ENg_Number.Value <> vbNullString Then
        
                Call oOutlook.SearchAndReply(Sup_ENg_Number, searchFolderName, True)        
                answer = MsgBox("Do you want to exit subRoutine ?", vbYesNo)
                            
                If answer = vbYes Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            End If
        End If
      
    Next Sup_ENg_Number

    MsgBox "Search and reply completed"

    ' Clean object
    Set testOutlook = Nothing

End Sub

'Then add a class module and name it: clsOutlook
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `AdvancedSearch` (which is asynchronous)? Use `MAPIFolder.Items.Find`. (where `MAPIFolder` is the folder you need to search, such as the Inbox retrieved using `Application.Session.GetDEfaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`).

Comment: Hi Dimitry, i need to search both my inbox and sent items , can i do that with "MAPIFolder.Items.Find" ?

Comment: You can search the two folders separately. Better than that, if you only expect or need a single match, `Items.Find` will be more efficient that `AdvancedSearch` or `Items.Restrict`.

Answer (score 0):

The code should first check if `Instant Search` is enabled in the default store to determine whether to use the `ci_phrasematch` keyword for an exact phrase match of "keyword" in the item body, or the `like` keyword to match any occurrence of "keyword" as an exact string or a substring in the item body. For example:

```
 Dim filter As String
    If (Application.Session.DefaultStore.IsInstantSearchEnabled) Then
        filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _
            & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) _
            & " ci_phrasematch 'office'"
    Else
        filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _
            & "urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" & Chr(34) _
            & " like '%office%'"
    End If
```

The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, `Instant Search` keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the Search class.

Read more about that in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Re: The event handler OutlookApp_AdvancedSearchComplete never fires.

I have to work around this event.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Get_LastMail_AdvSearch_URN_Subject()
    
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strFilter As String
    
    Dim strScope As String
    
    Dim objSearch As Search
    
    Dim fldrNm As String
    
    Dim rsts As results
    Dim rstObj As Object
    
    Debug.Print
    
     strScope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items', 'Deleted Items'"
    'strScope = "'Inbox', 'Sent Items'"
    Debug.Print "strScope............: " & strScope
    
    strSearch = "test"
    fldrNm = "Subject: " & strSearch
    Debug.Print fldrNm
    
    strFilter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject LIKE '%" & strSearch & "%'"
    Debug.Print strFilter

    Set objSearch = AdvancedSearch(scope:=strScope, Filter:=strFilter, SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="SearchFolder")
    
    ' The Application.AdvancedSearchComplete event is problem
    '  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearchcomplete
    '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909315/advanced-search-complete-event-not-firing-in-vba
    
    ' Saving may be enough. This would be ideal but not on my machine.
    ' You may have to delete a previously generated search folder before subsequent runs
    objSearch.Save fldrNm
    DoEvents
    Debug.Print fldrNm & " saved."
    
    Set rsts = objSearch.results
    Debug.Print " rsts.Count: " & rsts.Count
    
    If rsts.Count = 0 Then
    
        Debug.Print "Delay initiated."
        
        ' Delay to allow the search to complete
        Dim waitTime As Long
        Dim delay As Date
        
        ' Will surely be too little at the most inopportune time
        waitTime = 1    ' in seconds - adjust as needed
        Debug.Print vbCr & "Wait start: " & Now
            
        delay = DateAdd("s", waitTime, Now)
        Debug.Print "Wait until: " & delay
            
        Do Until Now > delay
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End If
    
    Set rsts = objSearch.results
    Debug.Print " rsts.Count: " & rsts.Count
    
    If rsts.Count > 0 Then
        rsts.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
        Set rstObj = rsts(1)
        Debug.Print rstObj.subject
    
    Else
        Debug.Print "no items found."
        
    End If

End Sub
```